# try_files directive being ignored when used with FastCGI

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, nginx-location

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy for PHP with PHP-FPM. I'm using the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;
  error_page 403 /error-403;
  error_page 404 /error-404;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
      set $fe_https 'on';
    }

    try_files $uri =400;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $fe_https;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
  }
}
```

I'm using the `try_files` directive, [as recommended](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php), for preventing uncontrolled requests to PHP.

However, after doing some testing, the `try_files` doesn't seem to do anything. If I request a URL with a non-existing .php file (like `/no-file.php`), I get a 404 error from PHP. Instead, I would expect a 400 error from nginx.

Am I missing something? The `try_files` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was. The issue was caused by the `if` clause:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
  set $fe_https 'on';
}
```

I am not sure exactly why, but removing it makes the `try_files` work.